# SQL server constraints for two fields so that exactly one of them must be NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with four fields, two of them are related so only in one of them have to be written value, another have to be NULL.

I mean, if both fields are `field1` and `field2`, the table should look like this:

```
field1  field2
NULL    value  -- correct
value   NULL   -- correct
NULL    NULL   -- incorrect
value   value  -- incorrect
```

Is there a way to make constraints or index, I'm not sure, in definition of the table so the field should be written like the example?

Comment: You will need to use VBA in MS Access. Try the BeforeUpdate event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using trigger `INSTEAD OF` (but be careful...).  Another way can be to build a stored procedure to make or not insert/update, and call the stored procedure from application.

Just for example (should be completed with check, error try, etc.):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID int NOT NULL, field1 int, field2 int);  
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD CONSTRAINT T1_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID);  
GO
CREATE TRIGGER T1_TRG_INS ON T1   
INSTEAD OF INSERT    
AS  
BEGIN  
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE (i.field1 IS NULL AND i.field2 IS NULL) OR (i.field1 IS NOT NULL AND i.field2 IS NOT NULL))  
  BEGIN  
     PRINT 'Data error.  No data inserted.'  
  END   
  ELSE BEGIN  
         INSERT INTO T1 (ID, field1, field2) SELECT ID, field1, field2 FROM inserted  
        END  
END  
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER T1_TRG_UPD ON T1   
INSTEAD OF UPDATE   
AS  
BEGIN  
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE (i.field1 IS NULL AND i.field2 IS NULL) OR (i.field1 IS NOT NULL AND i.field2 IS NOT NULL))  
  BEGIN  
     PRINT 'Data error.  No data updated.'  
  END   
  ELSE BEGIN  
         UPDATE T1 SET field1=i.field1, field2=i.field2  
         FROM inserted i WHERE T1.ID = i.ID  
        END  
END  
GO  
----testing-----
SELECT * FROM T1  
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, field1, field2) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);  -- NOT inserted  
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, field1, field2) VALUES (2, NULL, 1); -- inserted  
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, field1, field2) VALUES (3, 1, NULL); -- inserted  
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, field1, field2) VALUES (4, 1, 1); -- NOT inserted  
 
UPDATE T1 SET field1 = 1 WHERE ID=2   -- not updated  
UPDATE T1 SET field2 = 2 WHERE ID=2   -- updated  
UPDATE T1 SET field1 = NULL, field2=3 WHERE ID=2   -- updated  
UPDATE T1 SET field1 = 4, field2=NULL WHERE ID=2   -- updated  
UPDATE T1 SET field1 = 4, field2=5 WHERE ID=2   -- not updated
```